# Moving Values through a TStringGrid's Cells

Tags: delphi

The program I'm trying to create uses the Delphi `TStringGrid` component. Basically, I'm trying to make it so I can move the value `P` through the grid using 4 buttons: <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd>, and <kbd>Right</kbd>.

I can move the value of `P` up, down, or left.  But, for some reason, when I try to move it right, it fills the entire row with `0` instead of just the 1 element. I can't figure out why.

```
procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);//pressing the "right" button
var
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  for i :=  0 to Form2.StringGrid1.ColCount do
    for j := 0 to Form2.StringGrid1.RowCount do
      if StringGrid1.Cells[i, j] = 'P' then
      begin
        StringGrid1.Cells[i, j] := '0';
        StringGrid1.Cells[i+1, j] := 'P';
        { I have done the same for up, left and down (down would be j+1, left would be i-1, etc}
        break;
      end;
end;
```

This is how the program looks:

[image]

`P` is located at (7,7)

This is what happens when I press <kbd>Right</kbd>:

[image]

`P` was located at (3,6) and after pressing right, it changed the entire row to `0`.

Comment: The loop should go up to `ColCount - 1` and `RowCount - 1` respectively.

Comment: Well, you are iterating through the grid, so if you move the `P` in `0,0`, say, to `1,0`, then once `i` becomes `1` it will get moved again.

Comment: And when `i = ColCount - 1`, don't fill the next column with a 'P'.

Comment: Note that `break` breaks out of the nearest loop only (the `for j ...` loop). But why don't you simply keep track of the coords of `p` (px and py). At button press check if move is possible, set current pos to 0 and update `p` coords and update grid. No need for the loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tom Brunberg suggested in comments, it would be much more efficient and easier to manage if you keep track of the current position of `P` and remove the loops altogether.  For example:

```
private
  PColumn: Integer;
  PRow: Integer;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // populate the grid as needed...
  // place 'P' somewhere on the grid and keep track of it...
  PColumn := ...;
  PRow := ...;
end;

// pressing the "up" button
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PRow > 0 then
  begin
    Dec(PRow);
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn, PRow+1] := '0';
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn, PRow  ] := 'P';
  end;
end;

// pressing the "left" button
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PColumn > 0 then
  begin
    Dec(PColumn);
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn+1, PRow] := '0';
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn,   PRow] := 'P';
  end;
end;

// pressing the "down" button
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PRow < (StringGrid1.RowCount-1) then
  begin
    Inc(PRow);
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn, PRow-1] := '0';
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn, PRow  ] := 'P';
  end;
end;

// pressing the "right" button
procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if PColumn < (StringGrid1.ColCount-1) then
  begin
    Inc(PColumn);
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn-1, PRow] := '0';
    StringGrid1.Cells[PColumn,   PRow] := 'P';
  end;
end;
```